# Async load of Earth at Night map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to use this custom map when loading via JS API 3: https://earthbuilder.google.com/10446176163891957399-13737975182519107424-4/mapview/

I'm not sure how to use the provided API code addLayersToMap(map) and can't find that function anywhere in the documentation. I'm sure it's as easy as calling that function on the map, but that didn't seem to get me anywhere.

Here's my embed code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function initialize() {
              var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.26555,-110.961386)
              };

              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);

              var mapsEngineLayer = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
                layerId: '06673056454046135537-08896501997766553811',
                map: map
              });
            }
            function addLayersToMap(map) {
              // Handles to the layers created.  var layers = [];
              var layerKeys = [
              ""
              ];

              for (var i = 0; i < layerKeys.length; ++i) {
                layers.push(new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
                  mapId: "10446176163891957399-13737975182519107424-4",
                  layerKey: layerKeys[i],
                  map: map
                }));
              }
              return layers;
            }

            function loadScript()
            {
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOkhCBaoEKOhnpEJorFi83JSb0vIEkRg4&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }
            window.onload = loadScript();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out using [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/mapsenginelayer-noauth-layerkey?hl=en) from the API docs. Just pulled out one of the layers and replaced the map ID. Put this in the  and drop in your map-canvas div and you'll be golden.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=visualization"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42, -99),
        zoom: 5
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

      var mapsEngineLayer2 = new google.maps.visualization.MapsEngineLayer({
        mapId: '10446176163891957399-13737975182519107424-4',
        layerKey: 'layer_00001'
      });
      mapsEngineLayer2.setMap(map);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```